# Can I find all distinct table names that share a certain substring but not the entire table name?

Tags: mysql, database, substring, distinct, information-schema

I have a table of records that is formatted similar to the following:

```
AAA_backup_user1
AAA_backup_user2
AAA_backup_user3
BBB_backup_user1
BBB_backup_user2
```

If they share the same XXX_backup, they are treated as the same table and the extras will be deleted. Is there a MySQL command that I can use to get the distinct table names that prefix backup? Or anything to point me in the right direction. So only

```
AAA_backup_user1 
BBB_backup_user1
```

would be returned? Basically ignoring everything after the "backup_" part of the string.

Comment: If they all have 3 chars, then you can just use `LEFT()` to select the left three values from the column and group on that.

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r Unfortunately the number of characters varies greatly as it is a substantially large database. Is there something similar where i could do LEFT('_backup_')? Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: Yeah, you can use `LEFT(col_name, INSTR('_b'))` in order to do it.